# Where is my 'Run as' option in SQL Server 2008 Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-agent-job

I am trying to run an `.exe` as a command in a SQL Server 2008 Agent Job as another user. I see that this can be done by going to the Job's Step properties-Advanced' option however I have no option to set 'Run As' to run under a explicit account and password?

Anybody know where this is?

[image]

Comment: Did you look on the General page of that same window?

Comment: Yes, nothing there for 'run as'

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of that general page?  I have that option in my job setups.

Answer (score 1):

On the left, click on **General**:

[image]

[You may need to add a proxy.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175834(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: No, apologies. My issue is how do i set the job to run under a explicit account and password?

Comment: @Fearghal Follow the proxy link under the screenshot.

Comment: ok so i 'CREATE CREDENTIAL AlterEgo WITH IDENTITY = 'RettigB', 
    SECRET = 'sdrlk8$40-dksli87nNN8';' then i do what?

Comment: Ok i did this but still dont know where/what to do with my new credential - i have no option to choose it with in General or Advanced